# Enum property coming back with the wrong value after calling web-service

Tags: .net, web-services

I have the following enum on both client and server:

```
enum AddressType
{
    fax,
    ...
    email,
    voice
}
```

When my method gets called, I return an object which has AddressType as an attribute, and I explicitly set it to `AddressType.voice`

However, on the client, the received object has `AddressType.fax` instead...

What's odd is that everything else looks normal, and other enum types came back normally.

I checked and both client and server have the exact same enum definition, with the same order, and xml namespace. There is nothing in between to change this value.

I can't change the web-service interface as the web-service itself is a mock-up of another, and the client is a legacy application that runs a ton of stuff.

Any ideas on what could be happening here?

Thanks.

Comment: It's getting set to the first enum value, which is 0, suggesting the possibility that the value isn't getting serialized or deserialized at all.  Have you verified that it is getting serialized correctly?  Show us the class definition you're sending in the service.

Answer (score 0):

What web services framework are you using (WCF, ASPX, etc.)? Depending on the serializer in use, you may have to mark your properties as serializable explicitly.

For example, using the default `DataContractSerializer`, you need to place the `DataMember` attribute on every property or field that you want serialized. It sounds like the field isn't being serialized, as it's defaulting to the zero value. You can test this by changing the values assigned to each member of the enum, either by rearranging them and letting the automatically-assigned values differ, or specifying the values for each enum member explicitly in the definition. If the value always comes back as the value represented by zero, then (assuming that everything else like the property setter is working) the property isn't being serialized.